# Свой фрагмент в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! В моем фрагменте находится `RecyclerView` в котором находиться лента новостей. Как мне сунуть в `RecyclerView` свой баннер со скидкой к примеру на каждое третье место? Есть какой-то простой способ? Спасибо!

Comment: Наиболее распространенное решение - delegate adapter, с его использованием можно будет просто добавить в данные рекламные баннеры с нужной частотой. Статья на тему: https://habr.com/ru/post/341738/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете создавать `RecyclerAdapter` с множественными `ViewHolder-ами`.

- Для начала вам нужно определить для каждого `ViewHolder-а` создать отдельную `XML` разметку.
- После чего внутри адаптера вы можете переопределить метод `getItemViewType()`. Этот метод служит для определения того какой `ViewHolder` нужно подставить для конкретного айтема. Вот пример:

  ```
  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if (items.get(position) instanceOf Banner) {
          return TYPE_BANNER;
      } else {
          return TYPE_NORMAL;
      }
  }
  ```

  Где TYPE это просто переменная типа:

  ```
  private static int TYPE_BANNER = 1;
  private static int TYPE_NORMAL = 2;
  ```
- Далее вы создаете для каждого айтема свой `ViewHolder`, внутри которого вы прописываете логику биндинга вашей разметки.

  ```
  class BannerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     // Здесь вы как обычно прописываете то как будут биндится ваши View
  }
  class NormallViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     // Здесь вы как обычно прописываете то как будут биндится ваши View
  }
  ```
- Далее внутри метода `onCreateViewHolder()` вы определяете какой макет раздуть:

  ```
  @NonNull
  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
      View view;
      if (viewType == TYPE_BANNER) { // for banner layout
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_banner, viewGroup, false);
        return new BannerViewHolder(view);

    } else { // for normal layout
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_normal, viewGroup, false);
        return new NormalViewHolder(view);
    }
  ```

  }

  И аналогично в методе `onBindViewHolder()`:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
      if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_BANNER) {
          ((BannerViewHolder) viewHolder).bind(items.get(position));
      } else {
          ((NormalViewHolder) viewHolder).bind(items.get(position));
      }
  }
  ```
- Ну и последнее, что вам нужно сделать это подготовить список ваших данных. Для этого можно создать интерфейс - маркер и каждой моделькой (для рекламы и обычную) его имплементировать. Вот пример:

  ```
  interface ListItem {}

  class Banner implements ListItem {

      String bannerUrl;

      // геттеры/сеттеры и другие методы
  } 

  class Normal implements ListItem {

      String title;
      int count;

      // геттеры/сеттеры и другие методы
  }
  ```

  Создаете `List<ListItem>` и в него в нужном порядке кладете ваши элементы (тут как раз и можете задать на каждый 3ий рекламу. И этот список передаете в ваш адаптер.

Как написал @Alex_Skvortsov вы можете использовать и [делегаты](https://habr.com/ru/post/341738/). Этот подход лучше в перспективе, но и требует больше подготовки

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А есть пример готового кода?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/469557/ это немного более общая реализация, но для ваших целей подойдет. Внизу статьи есть ссылка на исходник